# How to append data in an empty array using Python

Tags: python, arrays

I was hoping to gather insight about what I am trying to do using python: So I have this array in my function that dynamically changes everytime. What I want to do is gather the multi-dimensional array data and put them together as a single array. Here is what I have been trying so far.

Code:

```
def myFunction(data,topic)
         data = data
         topic = topic
         pushed_data = []

         for ctr in range(len(data)):

             new_data = pushed_data.append([ctr]['topic'])

         print new_data
```

Output:

```
None
```

So I believe "None" corresponds to the array being unsuccessfully pass to the empty array. So what I would like to have as the contents would be

Preferred Output:

```
['topic1','topic2','topic3']
```

So If it is possible to achieve this without using additional python libraries then that would be great.

Comment: Which list do these `topic1` , etc come from?

Comment: "So I believe `None` corresponds to the array being unsuccessfully pass to the empty array." This belief is incorrect..

Comment: @AnandSKumar this would come from the data variable which generates the data dynamically

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 what would you call it then? can you elaborate please?

Comment: Try opening an interpreter, entering `my_list = [1,2,3]`, then `my_return = my_list.append(4)`, then `print(my_list)` and `print(my_return)`.

Comment: The way that this question was originally closed really underscores the need for the general canonical. Several list methods work the same way; the problem and solution are the same.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue in your code comes from the line -

```
new_data = pushed_data.append([ctr]['topic'])
```

`list.append()` is an in place operation, it does not return anything, which means it returns `None` by default and that is why `new_data` is always None. Instead of that , you just want to do - `pushed_data.append(...)` - without assigning the return variable to anything. And then you want to print `pushed_data` , not `new_data` .

Secondly, I am not really sure what this is supposed to be -

```
[ctr]['topic']
```

This should ideally give you an error like - `list indices must be integers, not str` - If you want to get the `topic` index from each row in `data` , then you should do -

```
pushed_data.append(data[ctr][topic])
```

If `data` contains dictionaries (if data is a list of dictionaries) and you really want the value for key `'topic'` , use - `data[ctr]['topic']` instead.

An easier way to do this would be to directly iterate over the elements of `data` instead of taking its length and iterating over the indices , since you do not really need the indices for anything else. Example -

```
for elem in data:
    new_data = pushed_data.append(elem[topic])
```

Also, you do not need to do -

```
data = data
topic = topic
```

That does not do anything.

Same can be achieved through list comprehension as -

```
def myFunction(data,topic)
     pushed_data = [elem[topic] for elem in data]
     print(pushed_data)
```